# Currency Conversion and display fetched from Server

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, itunes

I am fetching the in app purchase items for my app from my web server.the web-server gives the product title, description and price...

Currently i am displaying the each product using the product title,description and price.Currently i am showing the currency in $.

Now i am having the doubt that , can i display the prices as such?when i referred some URL, it seems that prices needs to be localized.

So do i need to display the prices localized which is fetched from my-server? please let me know how should i proceed?

Thanks a lot for stopping by..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should show localized prices.

From [App Store Quick Reference: Getting Started with In-App Purchase on iOS and OS X Lion](https://developer.apple.com/news/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf):

> Since your application may be available in App Stores with a region specific currency and 
>   language, your item’s localized description and pricing information should be pulled from the 
>   App Store via StoreKit’s products request API. You’ll use the information returned from the 
>   products request to populate the user interface you present to the customer for item selection 
>   and purchase

The product request API from StoreKit is pretty straightforward, it returns a ProductResponse, which contains an SKProduct, which includes both the price *and* the priceLocale. Per the [SKProduct Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/Reference/Reference.html), your code to format the price in the current local should be something like:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```